# Output Array<string> TypeScript type using wasm_bindgen on Rust struct field with type Vec<String>

Tags: rust, types, wasm-bindgen, rust-wasm

In the `project_wasm.d.ts` below, I'm trying to output `Array<string>` instead of the `Array<any>` coming from `js_sys::Array` - but can't figure out the correct `wasm_bindgen` syntax or getter function.  The calling TypeScript/NodeJS code works, but I want the more restricted type.

```
export class SampleResult {
  free(): void;
  readonly count: number | undefined;
  readonly errors: Array<any> | undefined;
  readonly result: string | undefined;
  readonly success: boolean;
}
```

The definition of `js_sys::Array` that produces `typescript_type = "Array<any>"`

```
#[wasm_bindgen(extends = Object, is_type_of = Array::is_array, typescript_type = "Array<any>")]
#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub type Array;
```

Below is the Rust code run through `wasm-pack build --target nodejs` which generates the above type definition.  The compiler does warn "unused variable: typescript_type" which explains why `Array<string>` isn't used.  Using `wasm-bindgen = "0.2.84"` and `js-sys = "0.3.61"`

**Question:** How can I output `typescript_type = "Array<string>"`?  Do I using something other that `js_sys::Array` or somehow extend or modify it?

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[wasm_bindgen(getter_with_clone)]
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct SampleResult {
    #[wasm_bindgen(readonly)]
    pub success: bool,
    #[wasm_bindgen(readonly)]
    pub count: Option<i32>,
    #[wasm_bindgen(readonly)]
    pub result: Option<String>,
    errors: Option<Vec<String>>,
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl SampleResult {
    #[wasm_bindgen(getter, typescript_type = "Array<string>")]
    pub fn errors(&self) -> Option<js_sys::Array> {
        if let Some(errors) = &self.errors {
            let arr = js_sys::Array::new_with_length(errors.len() as u32);
            for (i, s) in errors.iter().enumerate() {
                arr.set(i as u32, JsValue::from_str(s));
            }
            Some(arr)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to accomplish this for my use-case - hopefully it'll help you!

First, I define the methods I need for my

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
extern "C" {
    #[wasm_bindgen(js_class = Array, typescript_type = "Array<string>")]
    pub type StringArray;

    /// Creates a new empty array.
    #[wasm_bindgen(constructor, js_class = Array)]
    pub fn new() -> StringArray;

    #[wasm_bindgen(method, js_class = Array)]
    pub fn push(this: &StringArray, value: &JsValue) -> u32;
}
```

Then, I define the mappings from Rust to JS:

```rust
impl<A> std::iter::Extend<A> for StringArray
where
    A: AsRef<JsValue>,
{
    fn extend<T>(&mut self, iter: T)
    where
        T: IntoIterator<Item = A>,
    {
        for value in iter {
            self.push(value.as_ref());
        }
    }
}

impl<A> std::iter::FromIterator<A> for StringArray
where
    A: AsRef<JsValue>,
{
    fn from_iter<T: IntoIterator<Item = A>>(iter: T) -> Self {
        let mut out = StringArray::new();
        out.extend(iter);
        out
    }
}
```

and finally, I can invoke

```rust
fn get_values() -> StringArray {
    let s: Vec<String> = ...;
    s.iter().map(JsValue::from).collect()
}
```

You can steal the implementations from the `js_sys::Array` file.